# @Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => item.likevalue) is it possible to assign this value to local varible in razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, view

```
@Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => item.likevalue)
```

the above code will return either 1 or 0 i want to check the condition and like to display two different lables depending on the result 
is it possible to store it in a local variable in MVC Razor view

```
 @foreach (var item in Model)    {
 <div class="list-group-item card"> <div class="row-picture">                        
 <img class="circle" src="@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem=>item.Image)" alt="icon"> </div> 

 if(@Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => item.likevalue)==1)
 {
 //i want to display label1 
  }
 //i want to display label2
```

Comment: Can you explain your question a bit more? Do you want to toggle display of labels on the same view or after post?

Comment: Not clear, but I think you want something like `@if(Model.likeValue == 0) {<label>Label 1</label> } else { <label>Label 2</label> }`

Comment: i want to test the condition in every loop item as i am displaying list of items on the view for each iteration i want to check this condition
directly i cannot access 
modelItem => item.likevalue in view

Comment: Can you post more relevant code?

Comment: @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
             
            <div class="list-group-item card">
               
                <div class="row-picture">
                    <img class="circle" src="@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem=>item.Image)" alt="icon">
                </div>

Comment: so now i will get the likeval value @Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => item.likevalue) and i want to compare it with 0 or 1 then some logic to display two labels

Comment: Edit your question with the code (don't add it as comments)!